# floorEntry for Double numbers in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have divided a continuous range of double numbers into several sub-ranges. I tried to create a method in order to map each sub-range to a specific string value:

```
static NavigableMap < Double, String > RRMap = new TreeMap < Double, String > ();
static HashMap < String, Double > qualityMap = new HashMap < String, Double > ();

public static void main(String args[]) {

    qualityMap.put("Key", 0.3);
    RRMap.put(0.0, "A"); // 0..11     => Bradypnea
    RRMap.put(1.2, "B"); // 12..14    => Unreliable_Ranges
    RRMap.put(1.5, "C"); // 15..20    => Normal Activity
    RRMap.put(2.1, "D"); // 21..25    => Unreliable_Ranges
    RRMap.put(2.6, "E");

    method();

}

// lines of codes
public static void method() {

    System.out.println(floorEntry(qualityMap.get("Key")).getValue());

}
```

In the function named "method", I want to print the string value which is mapped to the number that exist in the qualityMap and is the value of "key". But it doesn't work and I encountered an error in the line:

```
     System.out.println(floorEntry(qualityMap.get("Key")).getValue());
```

It says that the floorEntry doesn't work for doublr number. I studied http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html but, there wasn't any restriction to the type of floorEntry arguman. I need guidance in order to map range of double numbers into a specific value.

Comment: Do you extend `TreeMap`? Also, can you post the exact error message?

Comment: `RRMap.floorEntry(0.3).getValue()` works fine for me.

Comment: Error Message: The method floorEntry(double) is undefined

Comment: @dacwe : it doesn't work too. It is the same work I have done; passing a double parameter to the floorEntry()

Comment: `floorEntry` is not a method in *your* class. You need to write `RRMap.floorEntry(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find out the problem. I changed that wrong line of code:

```
    System.out.println(RRMap.floorEntry(qualityMap.get("Key")).getValue());
```

And it works!